# Android offline install com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0

Tags: android, flutter

boycotting our country with all of our `IP`s by Google i can't build `Android` project which i made that with `Flutter`, so i get this error:

```
* What went wrong:                                                      
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'.                
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'.
   > Could not find builder-3.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:                               
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

now i can download this file and i want to know witch directory this file should be paste? i think after past this file i can install that offline

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier to add the jar to the gradle config:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('lib/local.jar')
}
```

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/put-jar-file-to-cache-manually/29488